# Simple html dom find not specified element

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

```
<div class="date">June<b>20</b><strong>friday</strong></div>
```

I'm trying to get only the month of this div but the problem is that month is not categorized by any other element. Is it possible to get the text that is inside div without taking other elements?

```
$date = $html->find('.date' , 0)->plaintext;
```

return June20friday. I need to get only June. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just apply a simple regex on your result:

```
$date = $html->find('.date' , 0)->plaintext;
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+/', $date, $matches);
$month = $matches[0];
```

Comment: But i should provide the months array or something to find matched or what?

Comment: No, it will work fine as long as `$date` starts with the month and follows with a number (here 20).

Comment: It means that no match was found... Oops! What does `$date` contains exactly?

Comment: June20friday wihout any spaces

Comment: Well, it should work then. Try to cast `$date` to string

Comment: Cast didn't help.Maybe the problem is in regex notation?

Comment: Taking this opportunity I wan't to ask one more question. The regex won't pass any other characters from A-Z yes? But what if i would have page in other language and there will be some special characters in month names?

Comment: In other languages, a major problem comes in: the order month/day may be different. Plus, special characters wouldn't be recognized by this regex, indeed.

Comment: Can i use then preg_match for example to check the matches from array of months? For example i would have $arr = ('June','July') in my array and will preg_match( $arr,$month,$matches) find the match?

Comment: With an array you need to use [preg_grep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($full_html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom); 
$xpath->query('div[@class="date"]');
$date->textContent
```

Textcontent is not a function, only a property so do not use brackets in the end.

Comment: It will get the whole div text as from my code provided,isn't it?

Comment: Well you can't get June only: reason: it hasn't got any immediate container element you can specify. So you simply can't. You get get the <b> and the <strong> tags separately and than do an str_replace on the whole text to replace those with empty. Or you can do a preg_match that would match any month if you know you are looking for string months. Or you can make a new DateTime object of the string, and than get the month. I think these aree your options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $text = $('.date').html();

  $array = $text.split('<b>');

  alert($array[0]);

});
```